# What is the reform mechanism of the European Union?

Tags: european-union

What is the reform mechanism of the European Union?

Is there a process built-in to the design of the EU to enable reform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Treaties

How the EU functions is documented in international treaties. The main ones are [Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Functioning_of_the_European_Union) and the [Treaty on European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_European_Union). The former was first signed in 1957 (and then known as the 'Treaty of Rome'), the latter was first signed in Maastricht in 1992 (and hence also know as 'Treaty of Maastricht').

Changes are made by creating and signing new treaties, which amend previous versions of the treaties. Examples are the [Treaty of Amsterdam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Amsterdam), 1999 and the [Treaty of Lisbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Lisbon), 2009.

Comment: Thank you. And how is the body of law developed through directives and regulations modified/evolved/repealed?